# React Hooks / localStorage

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am making a theme switch and I came across a following situation:

I have a key on localstorage where:

theme: `dark` or `light`

but if I change my key to something like red blue without quotes I get the following error:
×

> Error: A cross-origin error was thrown

**gif :**

[image]

I don't know I could avoid this situation in some way

my code:

```
export default function useTheme(defaultTheme = lightTheme) {
  const [theme, _setTheme] = useState(getInitialTheme);

  function getInitialTheme() {
    const savedTheme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('theme'));
    return savedTheme === 'dark' ? darkTheme : defaultTheme;
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(theme.type));
  }, [theme]);

  return {
    ...theme,
    setTheme: ({ setTheme, ...theme }) => {
      if (theme.type === 'dark') {
        return _setTheme(darkTheme);
      } else {
        return _setTheme(lightTheme);
      }
    },
  };
}
```

basically the problem is when I use JSON.parser

> ```
> const savedTheme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('theme'));
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing it from a string `"dark"` to just `red`. You need to use `"red"`

```js
const retreivedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme')
if (typeof retreivedTheme !== 'string') {
  // handle
  return
}
const savedTheme = JSON.parse(retreivedTheme);
return savedTheme === 'dark' ? darkTheme : defaultTheme;
```

Or if you just want to default to `dark` lets say.

```js
const retreivedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme')
const savedTheme = typeof retreivedTheme === 'string' ? JSON.parse(retreivedTheme) : "dark"
return savedTheme === 'dark' ? darkTheme : defaultTheme;
```

However, the only time it will not be a string is if the user manual opens dev tools to change it to some malformed value. Which should probably result in an error to show them they should not be doing this.

Comment: I know that I would like to know if there is a possibility to avoid this error when changing without quotes

Comment: I just wanted to prevent this error if they try to change it to value without quotes

Comment: assign `localStorage.getItem('theme')` to a variable. Then `console.log` that that to see what it returns when you change it to something without quotes. Then a simple `if` check before parsing it.

Comment: can give me one example?